# Flutter listen to lifecycle events on Stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter, statelesswidget, flutter-getx

Is there any solution for listening to lifecycle events for a StatelessWidget when the app is in background / foreground ? There is no StatefulWidget on that particular screen. I am using Getx() controller to observe data changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GetX architechture you dont have to use StatefulWidget but to listen lifecycle changes,
it seems like you have to use StatefulWidget.

Just override this method in a StatefulWidget.

```
  @override
Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async 
{
if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {}
else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for stateless widget

```
SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg) async {
  print('SystemChannels---> $msg');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

better use statefulwidgets for listen to lifecycle events